# replacing root relative paths in a wintersmith jade template

Tags: pug

Is there any way I can use a dynamic relative path in links instead of root relative paths in a wintersmith template?

I cannot use root realtive links such as `src="/scripts/main.js"` because the preview build server nests the website in arbitrarily deep subfolders , e.g.

```
/stage/workspace/build/scripts/main.js
/stage/workspace/build/index.html
/stage/workspace/build/about/index.html
```

On the production server everything will be under the root url so the root relative links work fine there, but I'd also like the builds to be viewable on our staging preview server.  How can I set up the links on my jade templates so that it will always use relative links,for instance a script link that is:  `../scripts/main.js` from the about us page while it is `scripts/main.js` from the home page.  I'd like to have both pages use the same jade template and the template figures out what the relative links should be for each page.

Is there some sort of get relative path function I can use in the Jade template based on where the content is in the tree in wintersmith?

Comment: use a function to generate scripts tag

Answer (score 1):

I use special **post-processing** build step that walks through all **generated HTML** files and **converts links** contained inside to their relative variants.

This method **works with any templating language** (e.g. [nunjucks](https://github.com/jbuck/wintersmith-nunjucks)) as it does not modify templates but the final deliverables.

It will not work with wintersmith's live preview server.

I use [Cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) HTML parser.

Core functionality goes like this:

```js
var cheerio = require("cheerio");
var fs = require("fs");
$ = cheerio.load(fs.readFileSync(expandFileName("build/test.html"), 'utf-8'));

// change all links in the cheerio document from absolute to relative.
// document's absolute location is supposed to be /test/test.html
rebaseDocument("/test/test.html", $);

fs.writeFileSync(expandFileName("build/test.new.html"), $.html());
return;

function rebaseDocument(documentLocation, $) {
  debugLog(documentLocation);
  rebaseElements(documentLocation, $, "a", "href");
  rebaseElements(documentLocation, $, "link", "href");
  rebaseElements(documentLocation, $, "script", "src");
  rebaseElements(documentLocation, $, "img", "src");
}

function rebaseElements(documentLocation, $, tagName, attributeName) {
  $(tagName).each(function() { $(this).attr(attributeName, rebaseLink(documentLocation, $(this).attr(attributeName))); });
}

function rebaseLink(documentLocation, link) {
  if (link == null)
    return link;

  // check if link denotes absolute hyperlink. If so, nothing to do here
  // absolute hyperlink is either scheme:// or protocol relative url //
  if ((new RegExp('^([a-z]+://|//)')).test(link))
    return link;

  // check another special forms of absolute hyperlinks
  if (link.substring(0, 7) == "mailto:")
    return link;

  // if link is already relative, nothing to do
  if (link.charAt(0) != '/')
    return link;

  if (documentLocation.charAt(0) != '/')
    documentLocation = '/' + documentLocation;

  var path = require("path");
  var documentName = path.basename(documentLocation);
  var from = path.dirname(documentLocation);
  var newLink = path.relative(from, link).replaceAll("\\", "/");

  // reduce 'document.htm#anchor' to '#anchor'
  if (newLink.slice(0, documentName.length + 1) == documentName + '#')
    newLink = newLink.slice(documentName.length);

  return newLink;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one solution I've been using is to use a different config for build:

so instead of using the default "config.json", in which will mess up your build
setup a config for specifically for build, ex: "config.build.json"
setup your urls how you want them to be setup, and when you're done,
just run:

```
wintersmith build -c config.build.json
```

(again, this is probably one of many solutions, I am also continuously looking for a better solution for deployment)